# Cannot mount hdd

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb, freebsd, disk

So I have a HDD which I have connected with an adapter via usb to my Ubuntu laptop. On connection a sound is made, but the disk is not automatically mounted.

After executing `fdisk -l` I get these results:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 149,1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Disk model: HD161HJ         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        4 312581807 312581804 149,1G a5 FreeBSD
```

So it turns out is a FreeBSD filesystem. Trying to mount it by executing `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disk`, gives an error:

```
mount: /dev/dvd: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Is there a way to over come this problem and read/write files to that hdd, **without** formatting it to another filesystem?

Comment: Type us the output of `# smartctl -a /dev/sdb`.

Comment: `smartctl 6.6 2017-11-05 r4594 [x86_64-linux-5.0.0-25-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-17, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Read Device Identity failed: scsi error unsupported scsi opcode`

Comment: Try `# smartctl -t short /dev/sdb`, wait 10 minutes, then type us `# smartctl -a /dev/sdb` again.

Answer (score 1):

If I try to mount a FreeBSD filesystem on my Linux host, I see the same error you report:

```
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

We can get additional details on that error by taking a look at the kernel log:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[...]
[1767775.494027] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem

                 mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...
```

So it looks like Linux won't mount a UFS filesystem unless we specify the `ufstype` option. Looking at the `mount` man page, it looks like the most likely option is `ufs2`:

```
              ufs2   Used in FreeBSD 5.x supported as read-write.
```

Everything else seems older (e.g., `44bsd`) or inappropriate (wrong OS).

If I run:

```
mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

It works...mostly:

```
$ dmesg | tail
[...]
Aug 23 10:01:09 madhatter kernel: ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
```

So depending on your distribution, you may or may not have *write* support available.

Comment: After executing `mount -t ufs -o ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb1 /mnt` I get the same error message as mentioned in my question. After executing `dmesg | tail` I get:
`sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdb: sdb1
sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
`

Comment: Interesting. What does `file - < /dev/sdb1` report?

Comment: `bash: /dev/sdb1: Permission denied` with sudo. (I have no idea what this command does).

Comment: You can't run commands with shell direction (e.g. `<`) via `sudo` (you would have `sudo su -` to root first, then run it). This uses the `file` command to attempt to identify the filesystem type. With the disk I'm using for testing, it reports `/dev/stdin: Unix Fast File system [v2] (little-endian) last mounted on /releng/12-amd64-GENERIC-release/usr/obj/usr/src/amd64.amd64/release/vm-image/new, volume name rootfs, last written at Fri Dec  7 01:13:35 2018, clean flag 1, readonly flag 0, number of blocks 7864320...`

Comment: `/dev/stdin: data` I got just this.

Comment: Well, that was less helpful than I had hoped :). Without having access to your device I'm out of ideas. I mean, you could try booting a FreeBSD VM and mounting it, but it's possible that the filesystem on that device (assuming there is one) is something other than what one might expect given the partition type.

Comment: It's a hdd from an old sony dvd player so no wonder it has a weird file system. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: fyi, you don't need to redirect a block device into `file`, you can use file's `-s` (aka `--special-files`) option.  e.g. `sudo file -s /dev/sdb1`.